# Conversion operators without overloading operators

Tags: c++

I am reading about conversion operators and got the gist of what they do. In a nutshell, they are pretty much needed when you want to convert from user-defined type to built-in types. There might be many more uses for that. A good example is:

```
class Tiny {
  int i;
  public:
    Tiny (int i) : i(i) {}   
    operator int() const { return i; }
};  

int main() {
  Tiny c1 = 2;
  int i = c1; 
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

This would output 2. Great. I understand that. Now to strengthen my understanding, consider this example:

```
class Tiny {
  public:
    class Bad_range {};
    Tiny (int i) {
      std::cout << "ctor called" << std::endl;
    }
    operator int() const {
      std::cout << "conversion ctor called" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
  Tiny c1 = 2;
  Tiny c2 = 62;
  Tiny c3 = c2 - c1;
}
```

This outputs:

```
ctor called
ctor called
conversion ctor called
conversion ctor called
ctor called
```

I understand how 'ctor called' came two times. I mean Tiny c1 = 2 indirectly means Tiny c1 = Tiny(2). So that is fine. WHAT I do not understand is why 'conversion ctor called' called twice.

Again, one more snapshot which included operator overloading:

```
class Tiny {
  int i;
  public:
    class Bad_range {}; 
    Tiny (int i) : i(i) {
      std::cout << "ctor called" << std::endl;
    }   
    operator int() const {
      std::cout << "conversion ctor called" << std::endl;
    }   
    Tiny operator-(Tiny a) {
      return this->i - a.i;
    }   
};  

int main() {
  Tiny c1 = 2;
  Tiny c2 = 62; 
  Tiny c3 = c2 - c1; 
}
```

This outputs :

```
ctor called
ctor called
ctor called
```

So, does this means that operator overloading gets high precedence than conversion operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you do not define an `operator-` for `Tiny` in the first example.  With:

```
Tiny c3 = c2 - c1;
```

In order for `c1 - c2` to compile, the compiler has to convert both operands to `int` and then use `int`'s `operator-`.  This happens as part of the standard conversion sequence that overload resolution uses to see if *any* overload of `operator-` can work.  Since you did not provide an overload, the compiler sees that it can convert both values to `int`, and so it calls that overload.